# How to resolve the Route value and Querystring conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I try to access the following controller action with the same querystring name as the input parameter I get a conflict.. For example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("get/{id}")] 
public object Get(string id){...}
```

^ Here `id` should be coming in from the url: `get/1` (so 1 is `id`)

Problem lies when I do this: `get/1?id=100`, it returns 100 as the value for `id`.  How do I resolve this conflict (without renaming the querystring name?)

I tried adding the `FromBody` attribute like so but that didn't solve anything:

```
public object Get([FromBody]string id){...}
```

It still overrides the querystring value over the param value from the url!

Comment: and you cannot rename either Route Parameter or query string param..?

Comment: because as far as the framework is concerned they are both matching parameter values by convention.

Comment: change your route attribute to [Route("get/{id=id}")] to use both query string and routing value as values for same action